# Nothing is getting displayed on the redirected page when login button is pressed

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my form page. When login is pressed, it is redirected to checkLogin page but it is empty. No echo is working.

```
<html>
    <title>User Login Form</title>
    <head></head>
    <body>

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="checkLogin.php">
    <td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" 
                bgcolor="#FFFFFF">        
    <tr>
    <td width="80">Username</td>
    <td width="6">:</td>
    <td width="300"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td width="6">:</td>
    <td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </form>

    </td>
    </tr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the checkLogin page
 This is not displaying anything.I tried mysql_error but still no display. Please help

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    echo "Check Login";
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];        
    $myusername=stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword=stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername=mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql="select j.jobid from jobs j,rcuser r where r.userName='$myusername'and r.password='$mypassword'";        
    echo "Hey".$myusername." ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($col=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr><th>Job Id</th>"</tr>;
            echo "<tr><td>" . $col['jobid'] . "</td><tr>";        
    }
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo $count;
    if($count==1){
       session_register("myusername");
       session_register("mypassword");
       session_start();
       if(!session_is_registered($myusername){
            echo "Session expired";        
       }
       echo "is it???";        
    }
    else{
       echo "Invalid Username or Password";
    }
?>
```

Comment: white page of death = error, but error checking\display is off

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem, Notice here: `Id</th>"</tr>;` You are not structuring your HTML and echo the right way. Check the below, where you mistake is.

```
echo "<tr><th>Job Id</th>"</tr>;
echo "<tr><td>" . $col['jobid'] . "</td><tr>";
```

Comment: I corrected it but still white page.                                                           echo "<tr><th>"."Job ID"."</th></tr>";                               echo "<tr><td>".$col['jobid']."</td></tr>"                           And even if i remove these html headers so as to print just the value of variable still the page is empty..

Comment: @Atihska then you should first try to echo out the result, just the username and password, if it echos out, then tell me and I will check again.

Comment: And, please put mysql error statement at the end of you equery like thi: $result=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

Comment: Ok, just give me some minutes

Comment: @Atihska, you can check my other answer and tell me the outcome

Answer (score 0):

Please check this script first, and tell me the outcome, as the way you have structured your codding is not clear enough.

`

```
$myusername=stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']));
$mypassword=stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mypassword']));

$sql=" SELECT j.jobid 
            FROM jobs j,rcuser r 
            WHERE r.userName='$myusername' AND r.password='$mypassword' ";        

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) === 1) {
echo "Username and Password is found";
}else {
echo "Error! No results found.";
}
```

?>`

Comment: Running your code, it displayed "Oops sth went wrong". This is the error msg that I am giving while establishing a connection. So its my connection problem? And 'wrong' word is hyperlinked with some advertisment. I havent made it so..

Comment: Also to be more specific, I am trying to establish a session. Is that wrong the way i am doing. Please suggest..

Comment: @Atihska leave the session, later I will help you to do that, but now check if your database connection is set, and tell me the exact error you are getting

Comment: Btw, in the `SELECT` statement there is a query like this: `FROM jobs j,rcuser r` you see the last `r`? What is it? did you make a mistake there?

Comment: no r is an alias just like j. My config file is this:               <?php
mysql_connect('servername','atihska','123456') or die("Oops something went wrong");
mysql_select_db('rcusers');

?>                                                                 And so my error message is Oops something went wrong.

Comment: I am sorry for the code not being properly posted. I pressed alt+k but its not editing. Apologies for inconvenience, I am a newbie right now..

Comment: Its Working now!!! I restarted the server and removed the clutter from the code.. Thanks a lot..:)

Comment: @Atihska no problem, I am glad to help. But, if you've found this answer helpfull, make sure to upvote or accept it.